# Laravel doesntHave() doesn't exist with relationship?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm creating some database seeding and I'm encountering an issue attaching related records to a pivot table I've setup.

I've got User, Track, Crate.

A user can have many crates and a crate can have many tracks.  And many tracks can belong to many crates.

Crate Model:

```
public function tracks()
{
    // Bring me a crate of those tracks dat boi
    return $this->hasMany(Track::class, 'crate_id');
}
```

I'm able to attach records but obviously since I've set both the crate_id & track_id as primary keeps (to prevent various user malarky) if I run my geniously designed seeding command line:

```
$tracks->each(function ($track) { 
    $crate = App\Crate::inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->get(); 
    $track->crate()->attach($crate);
});
```

I can really only run it once or twice.  After that it just fails, well, because for good reasons concerning primary keys.

So I thought plopping in the whereDoesntHave method into the query would only pull the crates where they aren't attached to any of this track id & crate_id and just pick a random one of those.

It doesn't seem to work.  So I pulled back and ran the code in tinker:

```
DB::table('crates')->doesntHave('track')->get();
```

And I get this:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::doesntHave()'
```

Utilizing & modify the example from this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe a lot of the language I utilized was a little difficult but I managed to think up something a little creative.  Using a php catch/try combined with do/while I was able to just carry on and keep calm so I could randomly attach some records.  I was even able to run this in tinker.

```
App\Track::chunk(50, function ($tracks){
    $tracks->each(function ($track){
        $attempts = 0; // Reset Each Attepts per track
        do { 
            try { 
                $track->crate()->attach(App\Crate::inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->get()); 
                // Attempt to attach a track to a random crate.
            }
                catch (Exception $e) { 
                    $attempts++; 
                    // If that doesn't work then 
                    continue; 
                } 
                break; 
            } 
        while($attempts < 2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure about what you are trying to do, maybe if you explained that I could suggest a better way to generate seed data.

The cause of your error is that Eloquent relationships are defined on the model, while you are trying to call the `doesntHave()` method on the `DB` facade which is used for running raw SQL. You should be good if you adjust your code like this,

```
App\Crate::doesntHave('track')->get();
```

Comment: I'm basically trying to seed test data using php artisan tinker (because hackerman) to help build out and test my various project functions. In this particular instance I've created a `crates` and `tracks` table and associated the two with a pivot table of `crate_track` and associated the relationship using the Eloquent relationship model where Crate `hasMany();` Track as per the `tracks()` method.  Once I've created a ton of crates using a Model Factory.  I need to then attach the relationships a bunch of times until a certain condition is met (# of queries that aren't attached < #).

Comment: Why not use Laravel's built in functionality for that? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding